# What "personal betrayal" is Charlie Lederer referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

This scene from *Mank* (2020) starts with a thick script hitting the table. A camera tilts up to show
Charlie Lederer standing and holding a hat. Then a wider angle shot reveals Herman is
sitting in a chair. Charlie Lederer is standing opposite to him and Rita, with binoculars,
is birdwatching. Charlie Lederer felt honored to read Herman's latest script:

> Charlie Lederer: Is this a test? Friendship? Loyalty? Or just your way
> of avoiding responsibility?
>
> Herman: What do you mean?
>
> Charlie Lederer: Are you hoping I might absolve you of such a **personal
> betrayal**? I won't give you that.

Then Herman gave "Citizen Kane" script copy to Lederer.

What "personal betrayal" is Charlie Lederer referring to?

Comment: Just a guess from reading [Charlie Lederer's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Lederer#Marion_Davies'_nephew).  Lederer was raised by his Aunt, Marion Davies.  Davies was mistress of William Randolf Hearst and Lederer spent much time at [Hearst Castle](https://hearstcastle.org/) and seems to have been close to both Davies and Hearst.  So I'm guessing the betrayal relates to writing of the script.  A guess however, I've not seen the movie.

Comment: As I always undestood it, it's because he knew, as an insider, and chose to reveal things only a relative or close residence employee would know. This kind of situation still happens nowadays and is frowned upon the same way (ie latest England royal family events)